# Does "may want to" mean the same as "will have to"? Are there nuances?

Tags: meaning, grammar

I read the following in an article  "When the Personal Becomes Political".

Is there any difference in the following sentences? (My bold to show the difference)

> 1. The agent, Sherry Wan, clearly does not speak English as her first language, so **you may want to** follow along with the transcript.
> 2. The agent, Sherry Wan, clearly does not speak English as her first language, so **you will have  to** follow along with the transcript.

Comment: The word "clearly" is a big red flag:  if you want to understand what she is saying, follow the transcript.   The two sentences mean the same thing, but the first sentence ("may want to follow...") is much more polite.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @ab2;  none of us like being told we *will have to do something*. Another way of putting it politely would be to say *so I'm afraid you will have to follow...*.

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is a difference in meaning between the two sentences.

> In the first example: 'you may want to' [follow along with the
>   transcript] implying this is optional.
>
> In the second example 'you will have to' [follow along with the
>   transcript] which implies if you do not, you will not be able to
>   understand the message.

Both statements are rude but the second is slightly stronger as it implies if you do not follow along with a transcript you will not be able to understand the message.

The first suggests it is optional to follow along with a transcript, the implication being it might improve your listening experience, but is not essential.

Comment: Just a suggestion: if a question is worth answering, isn't it worth up-voting?

Comment: What's "rude" about the statements?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I would say the tone is pejurative. "clearly does not speak English as her first language..." The use of the word clearly. The writer could have simply said "does not speak English as her first language..." So I certainly think it is rude, pejurative would have been a better fit, I was actually going to use the word pejurative but changed it given the nature of the question as I wanted to keep the vocab reasonably straight-forward.

Comment: @Gary: Sorry, I cannot agree. It is a straightforward, objective modifier denoting that there can be little or no doubt as to the agent's English-speaking status. There's no indication in the text that the speaker believes the agent to be a lesser human being for it.

Answer (score 2):

"May want to" and "will have to" are not the same.

In this context, "may want to" means: "you may have difficulty understanding the person's speech, in which case you might find the accompanying written transcript helpful."

On the other hand "will have to" means: "This person's speech is incomprehensible, so you will have no choice but to read the transcript if you want to understand."

The first is saying: "you might have trouble understanding," which is probably more polite than saying "you will definitely not be able to understand."

However, given the article title "when the personal becomes political," I wonder if you're asking about which part of the example is supposed to be offensive...

I would say neither "may want to" or "will have to" are offensive, though "may want to" is more polite since it leaves open the possibility that you might be able to understand the speaker. "Will have to" isn't necessarily offensive if the audio recording isn't so good or something like that, though.

The part that is offensive, I think, is "clearly." Comparing these two constructions:

> The agent *clearly* does not speak English as her first language.
>
> The agent does not speak English as her first language.

The first implies a value judgment while the second is only a statement of fact.

In the first case, the connotation is: "You can tell by how horrible her English is that she is not a native speaker."

In the second case, the connotation is simply: "English is not her native language."

So if you put that together, the least offensive construction would be:

> The agent, Sherry Wan, does not speak English as her first language, so you may want to follow along with the transcript.

This still strongly implies that she speaks English poorly, though. So if you wanted to be extra nice about it, you would just say:

> A transcript accompanies this video, in case you need it.

This construction does not name Sherry, nor place implicit blame on her English speaking. Perhaps the reason why "you might need a transcript" is still obvious when you hear the speaker, but because it is unstated it is less offensive.

Comment: I don't see what's "offensive" about the use of the word _clearly_. It is an objective observation that there is little or no doubt regarding the agent's English-speaking capabilities. People are astoundingly easily offended these days.

Comment: "Clearly" is not offensive, unless you really WANT to be offended.  You might as well argue that providing a transcript at all is offensive!
"May want to" conveys that the writer thinks you MAY not be able to understand the speech.  "Will have to" conveys that he is CERTAIN you won't be able to.

Comment: @LaurencePayne - if you read my answer, that's exactly what I said.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I think *clearly* as used in this way is emphasizing the importance of the statement, which to my ear conveys a value judgment. I'm not claiming it's *very* offensive, but, having worked with a lot of internationals over the years, I can easily imagine a situation where someone said this about a person who actually worked hard on their english and spoke it pretty well. In that case I would not be surprised if the international person felt a little disappointed and hurt that someone felt their english was so bad that a warning was required.

Comment: As far as whether or not people are "easily offended" these days, yes I agree that they are and yes I agree that it's often to a point that feels absurd to me. Nevertheless, anyone asking about how to word things may as well have context for what their words are going to convey to today's easily offended public.

Comment: @Andrew: Sure, but that has nothing to do with being offensive or rude. That's about someone being sad at the truth, which is an entirely different thing.

Comment: Well, maybe you don't hear a difference in your ear, but I think adding "clearly" rings of someone drawing emphasis to the "not being his first language", which conveys a value judgment, ie. "this person's english is terrible, so you'll have to read the transcript." Maybe the person's english is hard to understand, and nobody would argue that. But maybe someone is morbidly obese, and nobody would argue that either. Are you going to say "now this person is *clearly* morbidly obese, so you'll want to not sit next to them on a plane" and then expect them not to be offended because it's a fact?

Comment: @LaurencePayne Clearly you don't understand the answer. (See what I did there?) Yes, it does make it less polite to say clearly like this. It emphasizes something which doesn't need to be emphasized to convey the underlying meaning. It's persuasive rather than factual. It also suggests snobbery. "Clearly you are not a member of this country club" does not mean "I have inspected the country club roster and you are not on it." It means "It's obvious from your appearance/behavior that you are not the sort of person who belongs to this country club."

Comment: My point exactly, I completely concur with you both Andrew, @barbecue